# Send Image to server, Multipart.Part, Jetpack compose, retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want send profile image to server i use retrofit with jetpack compose, but i get this error:
400 Required Part [image] not specified
can u help me?

My composable

```
val photoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
        ) { uri ->
            if (uri != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                    profileImageBitmap.value =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ctx.contentResolver, uri)
                } else {
                    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(ctx.contentResolver, uri)
                    profileImageBitmap.value = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                    mainViewModel.uploadMyPhotoRequest(profileImageBitmap.value!!)
                }
            }
        }
```

My VM

```
fun uploadMyPhotoRequest(image: Bitmap) {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream)
        val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "avatar", "photo",
            byteArray.toRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull(), 0, byteArray.size)
        )
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                apiService.uploadPhoto(body)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.message
            }
        }
    }
```

apiService

```
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
    @Multipart
    @POST("photo")
    suspend fun uploadPhoto(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part)
```

i try this and get 400 code
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 28 not watch on code < api 28

Comment: Huh? Your code doesn't seem to do anything for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28`, just stores the value somewhere.

Comment: yep i test this on api > 28

Comment: This is why you make a [mre] first. Everything that's not relevant distracts from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your body as

```
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "avatar", "photo",
            byteArray.toRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull(), 0, byteArray.size)
        )
```

The error is

> Required Part [image] not specified

So, shouldn't you specify `"image"` instead of `"avatar"`?